# Trouble with a spatial data analysis in R request

Tags: statistics, raster, spatial, analysis, shapefile

I need help. I'm a beginner using R, and I'm having some issues dealing with a raster data base which structure and content is apparently considerably different from what I've already saw on spatial data courses and textbooks. Here's the metadata of the file:

http://terrabrasilis.dpi.inpe.br/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/507294db-a789-42dd-9158-9dea77d9293f

What I must do is compute the total deforestation area increment from year 2020 to 2021 (any two years would do) by municipality (stored in a separated shp file) of the Legal Amazon, using the tiff data above. The first problem is that I can't subset the years directly from the raster data to deal with them separately. There's also only one layer. It seems that the relevant attributes are stored in a txt file that comes within the zip file. I tried using aggregate, reclassify, mask  and area (and zonal) functions, but I'm stuck. Maybe I've read the file wrong? Anyway, any help is welcome!

Here's what I've done so far:

#### reading the shp and tiff data

library(sf)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(tidyverse)

mncp <- st_read("municipalities_legal_amazon.shp")

desm <- raster("PDigital2000_2022_AMZ_raster.tif")

## selecting one municipality (Belém)

i <- which(mncp$nome == "Belém")

belem <- mncp[i, ]

belem2 <- st_geometry(belem)

raster_belem <- crop(desm, extent(belem))

## visualizing

plot(raster_belem)
plot(belem2, add = TRUE)

## selecting for 2020 and 2021

px_value_21 <- "d2021"
px_value_20 <- "d2020"

belem_desm <- mask(raster_belem, raster_belem %in% c(px_value_20, px_value_21))

belem_desm_21 <- mask(raster_belem, raster_belem %in% c(px_value_21))
belem_desm_20 <- mask(raster_belem, raster_belem %in% c(px_value_20))